# how to parse json when we have one of object value as another object in typescriopt?

Tags: javascript, typescript

please some one tell  me how to get the pestdata from below json

```
[{"pests":[{"id":197,"type":"Pest","name":"टोमॅटोवरील फुलकिडे ","yield_loss":"10% to15%","message":"सध्या <pest\"pest_data\":[{\"Title\":\"फुलकिडीचा प्रादुर्भाव\",\"Description\":\"\",\"url_prod\":\"\",\"url_readmr\":\"\",\"file\":\"upload\\/2017\\/04\\/26\\/1493187664-1473365957.jpg\"}]>फुलकिडीचा प्रादुर्भाव</pest>.. }]...}]
```

Comment: You can use your choice of [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step

- Use JSON.parse : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse e.g. `const foo = JSON.parse('yourstring');`
- Then use array access e.g. `foo[0]` and object access e.g. `foo[0].pestdata`